# Why doesn't tab switching in tabView work after presenting and removing a modal in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I made a simple application that consists of a main window with a tab navigation where each tab has its own navigation controller.

I can switch tabs and see the First view or Second view depending on the chosen tab.

Now I add a new window (StartupView) with its own navigation controller (startupNavigationController).

In the app delegate of the main window/application I do present the startup window as follows:

```
@implementation NavigationCrapAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize tabBarController=_tabBarController;
@synthesize firstTabNavigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    StartupViewController *sv = [[StartupViewController alloc] init];     

    [[firstTabNavigationController topViewController] presentModalViewController:sv animated:NO];

    [[firstTabNavigationController topViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [sv release];

    return YES;
}
```

Immediately after showing it, I will remove it again (for simplicity, normally this will happen after an event).

Now the application launches, shows and hides the startupWindow, and shows the underlying main window again with the tabnavigation. However, there is one difference. Before adding and removing the modal startup window I was able to switch to another tab, now the application will abort when I switch tabs.

I get the message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in main.c. I have no clue what it tries to access though (what could have been accidentally be released in the meantime?).

Screenshot of project tree: http://www.roderik.net/xcode-tabs.png

I get the following backtrace (with bt command):

```
#0  0x00f2809f in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0290c1a7 in WebCore::failedToStartServiceErrorMessage ()
#2  0x0003d695 in +[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:pathIndex:forEvent:] ()
#3  0x0001d709 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#4  0x00ffb992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#5  0x00da3944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#6  0x00d03cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#7  0x00d00f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#8  0x00d00840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#9  0x00d00761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#10 0x00ffa1c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#11 0x00ffa289 in GSEventRun ()
#12 0x00022c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x00001e89 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff040) at main.m:14
```

Project files: http://www.roderik.net/NavigationCrap.zip

Comment: Hmm do you get any backtrace? Try using "bt" command after it crashes without telling you why and maybe there should be a bit more information, or if you're using threads, check every thread for errors.

Comment: @herz I added the backtrace, unfortunately I can't make much sense out of it. What surprises me is that it refers to the modal (GSEventRunModal) while the modal should not be involved anymore when switching tabs in the main window.

Comment: Well there's a "objc_msgSend" which means you are trying to send a message to a deallocated instance but I can't really tell you what it is. Maybe, just maybe, you need to release your StartupViewController right after is presented modally and let the parentViewController do the retain and release after dismissing it. Could you try it and tell me the results?

Comment: @herz Do you mean not to release it just after dismissing it?

Comment: @herz, I uploaded the project files as a zip. Maybe you can take a look at it (might be easier than describing the problem)

Comment: My finding is that it doesn't like the UIWindow object in the modal with a UINavigationController. A UIView does work, but can not be combined with a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you are trying to dismiss the view controller before it's even drawn.  Nothing gets drawn until after the code falls into the main event loop, which is after you exit your method.  Try calling your dismiss call using

```
[self performSelection:@selection(<myDismissMethod>) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
```

Where all myDismissmethod does is call your dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Comment: I will try that after the weekend (don't have a mac at home). However in the original app the modal was dismissed after using it (it consisted of three pages), so it was drawn for sure. For the sake of simplicity I made it like this to describe the problem.

Comment: I just tried it (performSelector I assume) and it added a 2.5s delay but it behaves the same. The modal does hide though just as in the original code, it crashes when switching tabs in the view that is behind.